# Instalação MSSQL 2014 express ou MSSQL 2016 PREVIEW

Tags: sql-server

Estou com o seguinte problema..
Instalei o MSSQL 2016 Preview em um servidor que só consigo ter acesso via Terminal Service

Autenticação do Windows - Administrador

O problema é que tudo que encontro para ajudar a instalar o MSSQL diz que tenho que conectar no Servidor e configurar acesso remoto,  mais para isso tenho que estar fisicamente em frente da maquina...

Tem alguma forma de eu conseguir configurar o acesso remoto ao Bancos MSSQL utilizando meu terminal service..
Já liberei as portas de Conexão no Firewall

Só que não tem como eu ir la no PC somente para configurar isso...

**Tem como Alterar o tipo de Autenticação sem a necessidade de refazer a instalação do MSSQL ?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço a ajuda
Gustavo Moreira de Castilho

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa imagem é do Management Studio já no acesso remoto? Ou é na sua máquina?

Comment: **Sim Cigano**... Esta imagem mostra o Management Studio no acesso remoto

Comment: Experimente conectar como '.\SQLEXPRESS'. Se der certo, coloco como resposta.

Comment: **Não Cigano** Mesmo problema !!!